# MySQL JOIN with COUNT performance

Tags: php, mysql

I've recently been trying to optimise our database to increase its scalability, and run into something that I've been unable to further optimize, but feels like there should be *something* I can do better. I currently have:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, COUNT(p.id) AS count
FROM brands b
LEFT JOIN products p ON b.id = p.brand_id
WHERE p.status = 'Accepted'
GROUP BY b.id
```

I will potentially be adding extra `WHERE` clauses to further filter products, so I've ruled out keeping a maintained count of accepted products on each brand record (which is probably a bad way to do things anyway).

The tables are `MyISAM`, `b.id`, `p.brand_id` and `p.status` are indexed. With ~500,000 products and ~1,000 brands, it's taking in the region of 2.5s. Is there something better I could be doing to get a list of brands with their product counts, or is that time-frame actually pretty reasonable for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: +1 for suggestion for left join..here it should be normal join instead of left but if in any special condition left join required then move p.status from where to after on clause with and...further query performance may be better if use normal join instead of left join but not sure....

Comment: what is status field data type and length..

Comment: @Zafar Malik: Thanks. I removed my comment, because Gordon is explaining the same thing in his answer.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Actually, that is a good point. It's currently a `VARCHAR`. If I could change it to something else (an `integer` probably, I don't want to use an enum in case I need to add more statuses later), would that significantly impact the speed?

Comment: definitely int will provide better performance than varchar...regarding enum it will kill the performance...so think to use either tinyint and you can mention description in comment or use char/varchar.....if right now you are not in possition to change your varchar field as int due to some reason then you can create index really on which length you required suppose mostly values are under 12 character and my column length is varchar(100) then i can set index idx_mycol(mycol(12))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, COUNT(p.id) AS count
FROM brands b LEFT JOIN
     products p
     ON b.id = p.brand_id
WHERE p.status = 'Accepted'
GROUP BY b.id;
```

I would suggests indexes on `products(status, brand_id)` and `brands(id, title)`.

However, your `WHERE` is turning the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`, so you should be specific about that.  Perhaps you really intend:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, COUNT(p.id) AS count
FROM brands b LEFT JOIN
     products p
     ON b.id = p.brand_id AND p.status = 'Accepted'
GROUP BY b.id;
```

This returns brands where the count is zero.  The original version does not (although the `LEFT JOIN` suggests that is your intention).

If so, then a correlated subquery can have better performance:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM products p
        WHERE b.id = p.brand_id AND p.status = 'Accepted'
       ) AS count
FROM brands b;
```

The best index for this query is `products(brand_id, status)`.

Comment: Thanks, moving the `p.status` check has sped it up by 15-20%.

Comment: @AJEllender: Moving the p.status to the ON clause was not meant to speed up the query, but to correct it. *Either* you want an outer join, then it has to be in the ON clause, *or* you want an inner join, then you should change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN (and placement of p.status doesn't matter then).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Ah, I see. Apologies, I'm rather new to actually managing the database beyond using Laravel's Eloquent. Some of the finer points, despite my best googling, are still a little hazy to me.

Implementing the extra index, and the subquery method have been incredibly helpful. Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: So: 1) You should accept Gordon's answer. 2) Have you made your mind up whether you need an outer join (LEFT JOIN) or INNER JOIN, i.e. do you want to see brands without products in your results or not?

Comment: 1) good point: Done. 2) Yes, I needed to keep zero-product brands, hence following your suggestion to use the subquery instead.